# How to use foreign keys in SQL Buddy?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlbuddy

I need to use foreign keys for update and cascade, etc.

```
ALTER TABLE topics
  ADD FOREIGN KEY(topic_by) REFERENCES users(user_id)
  ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

but I am not able to make foreign keys in SQL Buddy.

Any way to do that?

Comment: You did not mention your database name, put your database name prior to your tables name along with a dot (.)

Comment: Though not familiar with sql buddy, I have a comment. Do you get an error message, then please add it to your question. Possibly: wrong table name, wrong column name, autorisation issue (not autorised to alter), no connection to the right db. Or something.

Comment: I'm not familiar with SQL Buddy but check your database: Foreign Keys are not supported with **MyISAM**. Please be sure you're using **InnoDB**. See [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/storage-engines.html)

Answer (score 0):

did you try this :

```
ALTER TABLE topics 
ADD CONSTRAINT topic_by FOREIGN KEY(user) 
REFERENCES users(user_id) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
ALTER TABLE topics
ADD CONSTRAINT topic_by
FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(user_id);
```